# Excel VBA .Find ignores commas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that searches for a value in column A. the values are project numbers like 4545 and 3605. 
Sometimes a project does have multiple sub-projects. A subproject is determined as example: 3605,01 and 3605,02 etc..

I use .find to find the row of the project and after it is found, some data is pasted.

**The problem**

Numbers like 4545 works perfectly but when a comma is used, Excel doesn't seems to get it. I think he sees a comma as a point. How can I let Excel know that a comma is the decimal separator? Or is there another problem?

**This is my code:**

```
    Dim Projectnumber As String
    Projectnumber = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("A6").Value2
    Dim ThisProjectRow As Range
    With Workbooks(Bureauplanner).Sheets("planning").Range("A:A")
        Set ThisProjectRow = .Find(What:=Projectnumber, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False)
            If Not ThisProjectRow Is Nothing Then
            End If
    End With
```

Comment: You may try to replace `.Value` to `.Text` in the line `Projectnumber = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("A6").Value2`

Comment: My version of Excel (2019, Dutch) also works with decimal comma instead of decimal point. And I could not replicate your issue. Cells are found just fine. Trying to think why yours wouldn't.

Comment: @vitaliy Prushak .text is not working. Column A is in values and I use a filter in that column as well

Comment: @JvdV i'm using Excel 2019 Dutch as well

Comment: Right, was able to replicate now. The `String` data type is your culprit. For example: `.Find(What:=.Cells(6), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False)` will work

Comment: @JvdV it seems to work, can I replace the string with something? So I don't need to use .Cells(6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so your culprit is the `String` data type. You mentioned

> *"Column A is in values..."*

While you store your lookup value into a `String` data type, this means you are comparing two different data types > A `Double` vs. a `String`. I guess this doesn't sit well with VBA.

So there are two ways to overcome this issue here:

**1).** Turn column A into `String` formatted values.

Or.

**2).** Replace the `String` variable by a `Double` > `Dim ProjectNumber As Double`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it vice versa... Looking for a double value using CDbl():

```
Dim Projectnumber As String
 Projectnumber = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Planning").Range("A6").Value2
 Dim ThisProjectRow As Range
 With Workbooks(Bureauplanner).Sheets("planning").Range("A:A")
     Set ThisProjectRow = .Find(What:=CDbl(Projectnumber), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False)
         If Not ThisProjectRow Is Nothing Then
         End If
End With
```